# install redis: Failed listening on port 6379 (TCP), aborting

Tags: redis

[install redis: Failed listening on port 6379 (TCP), aborting.]
I just trying to install Redis. Then this error happened, someone please help me
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7thG.png

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a service up on port 6379 and you can't bind your address on this port. You should kill your already service that bind on port 6379 or bind your redis on new port like 6370.
you can check your up service by `netstat -nltp` or `ps aux`

Comment: netstat -nltp this shows me the program run in port so i killed it and its fine.thanks